# Dynamic value for get_option linked to taxonomy term_id?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, options

I'm saving info into "get_option" and it's working great. But the info I'm saving is the slug of a custom taxonomy. The problem is that if I change the slug of the custom taxonomy later, it doesn't change in the "get_option" in the options database table.

Is there a way to make the contents of the get_option value associated with the slug of a custom taxonomy term ID, no matter what I change the slug to?

```
function save_taxonomy_custom_meta( $term_id ) { 
    if ( isset( $_POST['brandcategory'] ) ) { 
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
        $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['brandcategory'] );
        foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
            if ( isset ( $_POST['brandcategory'][$key] ) ) {
                $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['brandcategory'][$key];
            }
        }
        // Save the option array.
        update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
    }
}
add_action( 'edited_post_tag', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Yes, there should be. Post the code that saves the data please.

Comment: function save_taxonomy_custom_meta( $term_id ) {
     if ( isset( $_POST['brandcategory'] ) ) {
      $t_id = $term_id;
  $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
     $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['brandcategory'] );
  foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
   if ( isset ( $_POST['brandcategory'][$key] ) ) {
    $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['brandcategory'][$key];
   }
  }
  // Save the option array.
  update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
 } 
}  
    add_action( 'edited_post_tag', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );

Comment: [Edit]. that code into the question please.